# Like to convert textarea into using wp_editor

Tags: wp-editor

In the first code below I would like to use `wp_editor` in lieu of the textarea.  The second code snippet shows what I'm trying to use in the first code while keeping all the arguments etc in the first code snippet.  I hope that makes sense.

Code Snippet 1:

```
/* Post editor */
function userpro_post_editor($i, $class, $args) {
    if (!isset($args['require_content'])) {$args['require_content'] = 1;} // default for content: required
    ?>
        <div class="userpro-field userpro-field-editor" data-key="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <div class="userpro-input">
            <?php

            if(isset($_GET['post_id']))
            {
                $post = get_post($_GET['post_id']);
                $content=apply_filters(`the_content`, $post->post_content);
            }else 
                $content='';    

                echo "<textarea data-custom-error='".__('Provide some content','userpro')."'data-required='".$args['require_content']."'  name='$class-$i' id='$class-$i' placeholder='".__('Enter content here...','userpro')."'>".$content."</textarea>";

            ?>
            </div>
        </div><div class="userpro-clear"></div>
    <?php
}
```

Second Code Snippet:

```
/* Post editor */
function userpro_post_editor($i, $class, $args) {
    ?>
        <div class="userpro-field userpro-field-editor" data-key="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <div class="userpro-input">
            <?php
                $settings = array(
                    'wpautop' => true,
                    'media_buttons' => true,
                    'teeny' => true,
                    'quicktags' => true,
                    'editor_class' => $class,
                    'textarea_rows' => 10,
                    'tinymce' => array( 
                    'content_css' => userpro_url . 'css/userpro-editor.css'
                    )
                );
                $editor_id = $class;
                $content = '';

                wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
            ?>
            </div>
        </div><div class="userpro-clear"></div>
    <?php
}
```

Thank you for your help!!
Pete

Comment: I was hoping someone might be able to help me with this?  It doesn't look like it would be THAT hard to do?